# Getting Onedrive link of current Word Online file from Task Pane Add-on

Tags: office365, office-addins, onedrive, office365-apps

I was wondering if it was possible to get the onedrive link from a TaskPane add-on. From what I know, If I make a new Word Online document, it saves it automatically to my one drive so I was wondering if I could retrieve the URL somehow. Specifically, I want the link where when you login on one drive and right click a document and choose get link, it gives you a URL. This is the URL I want.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the code is below. The key method here is getFilePropertiesAsync. OneDrive UI might give you a different link depending on whether you're sharing the document (and add-ins aren't aware of how the document is shared). But it's the correct URL of the document and can be used by anyone with permission to access it.

```
Office.context.document.getFilePropertiesAsync(
  function (asyncResult) {
    if (asyncResult.status == "failed") {
      doWhateverWith("Action failed with error: " + asyncResult.error.message);
    } else {
      doWhateverWith("The document location is: " + asyncResult.value.url);
    }
  }
);
```

-Michael (PM for Office add-ins)

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to get the URL of the document. The JavaScript API for Office 1.1 has a object `Office.context.document`. You can use its property `url` to get the path to the document - local or cloud.

```
var urlDoc = Office.context.document.url;
console.log(urlDoc)
```

For more details, check this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp161057.aspx